# How to create spaces between <input> elements in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

So far I have this:

```html
Position Applied For: <input type="text" name="position" value="Enter Position" size="20" /> Date: <input type="text" name="date" value="mm/dd/year" size="20" /> <br/>
<br/>
Name: <input type="text" name="last" value="Last Name" size="20" /> <input type="text" name="first" value="First Name" size="20"/> <input type="text" name="middle" value="Middle Name" size="20" /> Phone: <input type="text" name="phone" value="Area Code First" size="20" maxlength="12"/> (Seperate with -) <br/>
<br/>
Address: <input type="text" name="address" value="Address" size="20" /> City: <input type="text" name="city" value="City" size="20" /> State: <input type="text" name="state" value="State" size="20" /> Zip Code: <input type="text" name="zip" value="Zip Code" size="20" maxlength="5"/> <br/>
```

When it shows up in the browser the forms are right next to each other. How do I get some room put between and nicely aligned?

Comment: How do you want them lined up? One on each line? I see you added some `<br>` elements. Are those the only breaks you want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use ul and css:

```css
  #a-form {list-style: none; margin:0; padding: 0;}
    #a-form li {}
    #a-form input {display:inline-block; margin-right: 1em;}
```

```html
<ul id="a-form">
      <li>Position Applied For: <input type="text" name="position" value="Enter Position" size="20" /> Date: <input type="text" name="date" value="mm/dd/year" size="20" /></li>
      <li>Name: <input type="text" name="last" value="Last Name" size="20" /> <input type="text" name="first" value="First Name" size="20"/> <input type="text" name="middle" value="Middle Name" size="20" /> Phone: <input type="text" name="phone" value="Area Code First" size="20" maxlength="12"/> (Seperate with -)</li>
      <li>Address: <input type="text" name="address" value="Address" size="20" /> City: <input type="text" name="city" value="City" size="20" /> State: <input type="text" name="state" value="State" size="20" /> Zip Code: <input type="text" name="zip" value="Zip Code" size="20" maxlength="5"/></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: thank you! I found there are many ways to do it, but decided to go with your method.

Answer (score 1):

Since they are all text fields, it makes it easier! I would suggest using the CSS display:block feature

Here's the CSS:

```
input[type="text"]{
display:block;
margin-bottom:20px;
}
```

and here's your example that [I put into JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pcanella/Qvynd/1/). You may need to do some tweaking to get it to your liking, but this is the easiest way I can think of!

Answer (score -1):

Many people may suggest something else, but I recommend you use a `<table>` in your case.

Comment: The content is not tabular data. And we wouldn't use `<table>` elements for styling when there is CSS, because that would be just silly ;)

Comment: @Ktash When we want to align our contents in a grid-like layout, table fits better in most cases.  Of coz we can apply some CSS + javascript hacks to mimic similar outcome, but it will result in unnecessarily complicated codes which is very bad for maintenance.  Many web designers advocate using CSS strictly over table for styling, but in the programming reign, less, clearer, and hence easier to maintain code is what we need.  Anyway, the OP doesn't seem to have the need to align the contents in grid, which is what I thought he/she wanted from reading the question.

Comment: `<table>` layouts are far harder to maintain. I am a web programmer, not a designer, and CSS is far easier to maintain. Separation of style and presentation makes maintenance, updating, and upgrading much easier, and modern browsers support enough CSS to handle anything a `<table>` can do. The person who sort of started `<table>` based design wrote an interesting article in 1997 on how he ruined the internet. It's a good read if you are interested http://www.xml.com/pub/a/w3j/s1.people.html

Comment: @Ktash I do agree that nowadays table is considered bad for layouts in most cases, especially when people use it to layout an entire page.  And I did suffer a lot from developers nesting tables one under another.  I also agree that separating style from presentation (probably in different files) makes *editing* easier, but it doesn't automatically mean the same to overall maintenance.  When we need to align our contents in multi-rows and -columns (i.e. anything more complicated than a 3x3), `<table>` fits in the best.  And no, `div`s and `span`s with fixed widths just don't cut it.